# Firebase Firestore Query Between Two Timestamps

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want to find events that are a on now and upcoming (next 30 days) but that are also not in the past.

When i run this as a cloud function, I get "Cannot have inequality filters on multiple properties". How am I meant to get this type of data.

(ignore the fact that the date stuff is a bit messy, am still playing around).

```
// Create date 30 days in future
const searchData: Date = new Date();
searchData.setDate(searchData.getDate() + 30);

// Load data and handle empty respoonse
const response: admin.firestore.QuerySnapshot = await admin
    .firestore()
    .collection(Collections.EVENTS)
    .where("startDate", "<=", admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(searchData.valueOf()))
    .where("endDate", ">=", admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(new Date().valueOf()))
    .where("public", "==", true)
    .limit(NUMBER_OF_EVENTS)
    .get();
```

Edit:
I would like to know the data structure/query method that will allow me to return all events in the events collection that are on now or that will start in the next month. Additionally, I would like the query to exclude events that have already finished. Each document (event) has a startDate and endDate timestamp on it.

Comment: You can't have use a range comparison on multiple fields in a single query, but if you edit the question to say what your query is supposed to do (in English), there might be a workaround that we can help with. It might involve performing two queries and merging the results.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I’ve update the question at the bottom I’m with a description of the behaviour I am looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Your question helped me a lot (the question indeed. I don't even scroll to answers hahah). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have two fields to check with ranges, I'm not sure this is doable with a single query.  What you can do instead is perform two queries, merge the results on the client, and perform a final filter to get the exact matches.

1. Make an assumption about the maximum duration for an event.  Call that amount of time "X".
2. Query for all documents where startDate is greater than now - X, and also less than now + 30 days.  Call this result set "A".
3. Query for all documents where endDate is greater than now, and also less than now + 30 days.  Call this result set "B".
4. On the client, iterate all the results from A and B, checking to see if the start and end dates fit the criteria you want.

I can't think of a way to structure your data that will do this with a single query.

Comment: This is a bad solution on large datasets.

Comment: @OliverDixon If you have a better option, I'd love to see your solution.  Given the query constrants of Firestore (only one range filter per query) combined with this document schema (start and end date being separated), there don't seem to be many other options.  Either change the schema to support the required query, or accept that this requires some extra overhead.

Comment: it's a real issue with Firestore! We have a database where this could return 10,000's of results. Our solution is to use 'select' otherwise the server crashes!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind a old thread, but the answer might be good for others.

What you can do as I at the end ended up doing, is that you have a $start_date and a $target_date.

You then do like this:

```
<?php
$start = strtotime('2021-11-22');
$target = strtotime('2022-01-01 0:00:00');

$limit = (($target - $start) / 86400);

$query = $col_data->where('date.day_start', '>=', $start);
$query = $query->limit($limit);

?>
```

Not bad, eh? You welcome!

Comment: Do you mind explaining what the limit does here? it will only get documents that are the start + limit from the day_start?

Answer (score -3):

From the docs:

> You can only perform range comparisons (<, <=, >, >=) on a single field, and you can include at most one array-contains or array-contains-any clause in a compound query:

```
citiesRef.where("state", ">=", "CA").where("state", "<=", "IN");
citiesRef.where("state", "==", "CA").where("population", ">", 1000000);
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: This does not provide any solutions to the issue, but rather re-iterates what the OP already knows.

Comment: @SizzlingSquiggle It did answer the question before OP did the edit. OP recieved and error and this answer explains to them why they recieved the error. Also given the limitation In queries in Firestore, this is the best solution.